# How to pass the value in both GET & POST way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, get, server

This is a simple BMI calculation web program

[image]
[image]

BMI_controller.rb

```
 class BmiController < ApplicationController
      def enter
  end

  def calculate
    @height = params[:height].to_f
    @weight = params[:weight].to_f
   @bmi=(@weight/(@height*@height))
   @category

    if @bmi<18.5 
        @category= "Underweight"

  end
   if @bmi>18.5 and @bmi<23
        @category="Normal"

  end

if @bmi>23 and @bmi<25
    @category= "Overweight"

  end


   if @bmi>25
    @category="Obese"

  end

  
end
end
```

calculate.html.erb

```
  <p>Height: <%= @height %></p>
<p>Weight: <%= @weight %></p>
<p>BMI: <%= @bmi %></p>
<p>Category: <%= @category %></p>
```

Enter_data.html.erb

```
`<h1>Welcome to BMI Calculator</h1>

<form action="http://localhost:3000/bmi/calculate?height=@height&weight=@weight" >
<p>Height: <input type="text" name="height"></p>
<p>Weight: <input type="text" name="weight"></p>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" namevalue="Calculate" >
</form>`
```

I use this way to past the @height and @weight to next page and calculate

```
 `<form action="http://localhost:3000/bmi/calculate?height=@height&weight=@weight"` >
```

The way I using is it called `GET` ?
However ,how to do the standard `method="get"` and `method="post"` respectively ?

## Update

However,I found that `<form action="http://localhost:3000/bmi/calculate?height=1&weight=23212" >` or `<form action="Calculate" >//<<=this should refer back to the function- calculate` work too.

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question clearly, but I'll try to explain a couple of things I think you may be confused about.

If you use `<form method="get" action="http://example.com/action">` you'll send a GET request and see the form elements in the URL, e.g. http://example.com/action?height=72&weight=90.

As you know, `method="post"` will POST the request. If you're using the same action, e.g. http://example.com/action, you'll need to make sure you're handling both GET and POST.

In your config/routes.rb file you'll want to make sure you can process the POST request. You should read up http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using rails I would use the helper method `form_tag`, instead of writing it out in html. By default the form submission is considered a POST request, but you can use other http verbs by passing an optional :method param:

Example: `form_tag(<path>, method: :get)`

The path should be defined in your routes.rb file with the correct http verbs.